# Developing a Windows Hybrid App for Partner Users - What Toolkit?

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api, partner-portal, forcetk

I am developing a Phonegap app for Partner users. It needs to be on javascript so I tried ForceTK with no luck. Is this possible?

Comment: How is this question related to the title?

Comment: d0001, in general a question makes more sense if you explain it with more deail. And user tags relevant to the question. There's a lot of contradiction between your title,tags and the question as-is. Would you mind clarifying your context ?

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's a good reason to use PhoneGap and ForceTk directly, you should be using the Force.com Mobile SDK. It is available for both iOS and Android and has native and hybrid templates which offer wrappers to the Force.com REST API and has Cordova (aka PhoneGap) bundled in it for device feature access and packaging up your apps.

Comment: Need to support windows 8

Comment: You should then be looking at using this toolkit - https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/01/announcing-the-salesforce-toolkits-for-net.html

Comment: The question is about portal users. None of those kits address the issue.

Comment: d0001 it may help if you add more clarification to the question. The exact problem you are facing isn't quite clear in your question.